# Is there a function in excel to repeat the formulas in excel using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

how can i set a formula in excel in a particular cell, such that each time i use a  keyboard shortcut it automatically computes it?, I need to compute the average of each column in B11, C11, D11 and so on with a shortcut(not dragging the formula or changing references).

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please be sure to upvote / accept an answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will detect the last row in the first column and the last column, then will loop through the data starting at column 2.

> - Open Excel VBA (ALT-F11)
> - Right click VBAProject and Insert > Module
> - Copy the following code to the newly created module
> - Attach a hotkey (ALT-F8 > Options) to the macro.

```
Sub avgcol()
    Dim lRow, lCol, i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 2 To lCol
        ws.Cells(lRow + 1, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lRow, i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```